# Controller class LoginController could not be found

Tags: cakephp

I have created very basic AdminController.php which is initially being correctly showen on http://mysite/admin  but when I try to access the controller action http://mysite/admin/search  I end up with “Controller class LoginController could not be found.”

My controller:

```
<?php
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');
class AdminController extends AppController {

    public function index(){ echo 'controller index'; die(); }
    public function search() {
        echo "controller action serach"; die();
    }   
}
```

Router:

```
CakePlugin::routes();
require CAKE . 'Config' . DS . 'routes.php';
Router::connect('/admin', array('controller' => 'admin', 'action' => 'search' ));
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have the Auth component on and haven't specifically set that action to be allowed.  Therefore, it's saying "woah, you can't go there", and redirecting to the login page.

Side note - you're using non-standard naming conventions.  Controller names should be plural.   In your case, you set up a single route that will handle what happens if they type "/admin" specifically, but the rest aren't handled - could be an issue.

Comment: Yes your analyze is correct I have fixed the login redirection with adding the search page into before filter => $this->Auth->allow('search'); Regarding your side note I have a problem with routing because when I rename the controller to AdminsController I end up with http://mysite/admins url and I would prefer more http://mysite/admin . I will open anther topic for this.